# Failed to establish connection error in Jenkins with Integrity plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, mks-integrity

I am trying to connect MKS Integrity client with Jenkins. I am running Jenkins as a windows package. After entring my credentials i get the following

> Failed to establish connection error.

My setup: **Jenkins: 1.609**, **Integrity plugin : 1.34.**

Both jenkins and integrity are up and running.The Log file looks as follows:

> Jenkins is fully up and running Aug 21, 2015 12:43:36 PM INFORMATION
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetryI/O
>   exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request:
>   Connection refused: connect Aug 21, 2015 12:43:36 PM INFORMATION
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector
>   executeWithRetryRetrying request Aug 21, 2015 12:43:37 PM INFORMATION
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetryI/O
>   exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request:
>   Connection refused: connect Aug 21, 2015 12:43:37 PM INFORMATION
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector
>   executeWithRetryRetrying request Aug 21, 2015 12:43:38 PM INFORMATION
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector executeWithRetryI/O
>   exception (java.net.ConnectException) caught when processing request:
>   Connection refused: connect Aug 21, 2015 12:43:38 PM INFORMATION
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector
>   executeWithRetryRetrying request Aug 21, 2015 12:43:39 PM
>   SCHWERWIEGEND hudson.scm.APISession createAPI Exception caught... Aug
>   21, 2015 12:43:39 PM SCHWERWIEGEND hudson.scm.APISession
>   createConnection refused: connect Aug 21, 2015 12:43:39 PM
>   SCHWERWIEGEND hudson.scm.APISession createAPIException

[![Jenkins Log][1]][1]
Trial Solution 1:I googled out the possible solutions for this error but wasn't helpful.
1. Destination host is ping-able
2. We can connect to server host and port using telnet.
Please find link below where the solutions were suggested for the **Connection refused error** Link: *http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2013/02/java-net-ConnectException-Connection-refused.html*

Trial Solution 2:
I have eveb added my ip address in the Integrityclientsite.rc file as suggested in the PTC community link

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with few more resolutions few of them are listed below:
1. Downgrading my Integrity version to V1.32 - Not successful
2. Downgrading my Java version to V1.7 - Not successful
3. Changed the integration port name from 31001 to 31000(default for port running on Windows OS) - Successful
The third resoultion i found it from one of the comments as a resolution for another issue on Jenkins community.
PFB the link https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-18445?jql=text%20~%20%22integrity%22